# Rails: Searching (query) through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to get results from associations. I want to get all the members that paid the ticket for a specific event. The name of the event is Lead.

```
class Pages::EventsController < ApplicationController
 @total_paid = Member.includes(event: :lead).where('events.lead.paid = ?', true)
end
```

When I run `@total_paid.count` I get, from the console:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" WHERE (events.lead.paid = 't')

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry 
for table "lead"

LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" WHERE (events.lead.paid = 't'...
```

Below is the structure of my associations:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :members
 has_one :lead
end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
end

Class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :event
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. This should do the trick:

```
@total_paid = Member.includes(event: :lead).where('leads.paid = ?', true).references(event: :lead)
```

Simply add `references` in the end and change the query to only `leads`.

Answer (score 0):

postgres is not ruby... you can't do: `events.lead.paid`, you can only refer to individual tables, and use the table-name (which is usually pluralized)

```
Member.includes(event: :lead).where('leads.paid = ?', true)
```

though I would prefer to also use fewer variables eg

```
Member.includes(event: :lead).where('leads.paid IS TRUE')
```

You might also need to use `references` to tell Rails that you'll be directly referring to the leads table eg:

```
Member.includes(event: :lead).where('leads.paid IS TRUE').references(:leads)
```

Comment: I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "leads"`

Comment: then you should use whatever is the name of the table that contains your leads...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the name of the table is `leads` and it is associated with table `events`

Comment: ok, so open up `rails c` and type: `Member.includes(event: :lead).where('leads.paid IS TRUE').to_sql` -> save what it returns and add it to your question...

Comment: also you might need to add `references` (I'll update the answer)

Answer (score 0):

[Taryn East](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219883/taryn-east) has got the right idea.

Your table name is singular, so it should be `lead` instead of `leads` Try:

```
Member.includes(event: :lead).where('lead.paid IS TRUE')
```